# Demolish the [plain] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [plain](/questions/tagged/plain) tag is entirely undescriptive, and serves no real purpose. It's often used for [plaintext](/questions/tagged/plaintext), but also instead of [plane](/questions/tagged/plane) by non-native speakers.

They call to me: *"You should kill us all on sight."*

Comment: So it is plain to you that the plain tag is plainly lacking in purpose?

Comment: Have I not made that plain enough?

Comment: Since I’m retagging [plain], [text] -> [plaintext] right now, I would have asked for this soon as well.

Comment: I do see one other use, and that is for plain objects (i.e. plain Java object, or plain CLR object). I suppose that could be fixed by adding a [plain-object] tag (if one doesn't already exist). I'll retag the one or two questions I see with it.

Comment: Are you talking about plain old datatype objects? Because I was going to request a [plain-old-datatype] tag soon.

Comment: @Adrian Yes. Although on second thought, we already have tags like [tag:poco] and [tag:pojo]. Aren't all these questions going to be language-specific anyway? Do we really need [plain-old-datatype] or [plain-old-object]?

Comment: @CodyGray I didn’t know about the language-specific versions, thanks. `plain old datatype` or as wikipedia calls it [plain old datastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure), is something a bit different, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the combined efforts of Adrian Lang, myself, and possibly a few others who happened by this question, the [plain](/questions/tagged/plain) tag [has been burninated on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plain). With no associated questions, it will be automatically deleted by the system in approximately 24 hours.

I don't think there's any reason to make [plain](/questions/tagged/plain) a synonym of any other tag, so unless someone wants to argue for blacklisting it, I hereby declare this request [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: I congratulate your efforts, but just a small question on terminology: Isn't "burninate" usually reserved for the act of destruction via non-mortal means by mods (or devs)?

Comment: @Joachim No, not in my opinion. It's just a meme that refers to the removal of an inappropriate tag. There are multiple ways to burninate, some of them requiring moderator intervention, others not. Removing the tag from all questions makes the most sense when the questions also need to be *retagged* (and a synonym is not applicable). As I explained, unused tags are automatically deleted.

Comment: nuh uh, the end result is the same (tag "disappears") but the path is different.